# Using Arduino Lily Pad together with HC-6 bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am thinking of doing a project with wearable electronics. 
First off I was wondering if you can connect the HC-6 Bluetooth device to the Lilly Pad, to send data to a computer via Bluetooth? or do I absolutely have to buy the "expensive" Bluetooth Mate?

Second, if the above is not possible, what is the smartest and cheapest solution for sending data from a Lily Pad to a computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not. First off, this tutorial shows you how to attach the HC-06 to an Arduino Uno: http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-bluetooth-to-your-Arduino-project-ArduinoHC-06/?ALLSTEPS

Even though you are using a Lilypad, the pins are the same. Here is a pinout diagram for the Lilypad: http://figures.oreilly.com/tagoreillycom20090710oreillybooks308088I_book_d1e1/figs/I_mediaobject5_d1e21363-web.png

This does a decent job of explaining Bluetooth serial communication for Macs: https://decyborg.wordpress.com/2013/09/08/bluetooth-serial-communication-with-arduino-jy-mcu-bluetooth-and-macbook-pro/

Or you could check this out for Windows: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/bluetooth-serial-terminal/9wzdncrdfst8

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer:-).. It is really helpful.